# Is there any way to add git specific version into Linux "capabilities" in the azure devops agent pool

Tags: linux, git, azure-devops, redhat, software-collections

We have a GIT installed using YUM in our linux RHEL 7.9. Right now, our azure devops linux build agents are able to recognize this GIT 2.24.2 and everything working fine. But moving forward we like to use the GIT 2.29 which we installed recently from [REDHAT software collection](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-git29/)  using the below commands;

on top we have also added this into our service account bash profile as well. I can see the git location as /bin/git in the azure devops agent capabilities screen (image attached). On that hand, when I get into linux machine I don't see any git installed on that /bin/git path.

Currently, we are looking for a way to make this azure devops agent to recognize the GIT which we installed using Redhat software collection

1. Install the collection:

   ```
   $ sudo yum install rh-git29
   ```
2. Start using the software collection:

   ```
   $ scl enable rh-git29 bash
   ```
3. Linux build agent capabilities screenshot

[image]